# How do I get the "Ow My Balls!" achievement?

Tags: achievements, saints-row-the-third

The description for the "Ow My Balls!" achievement reads as follows:

- `Do your first nutshot AND testicle assault.`

I've made several nutshots so far and I've also done several testicle assaults but this achievement hasn't popped for me yet. To that end, I have a few questions about how to get this.

- **Do I have to do a nutshot and a testicle assault on the same enemy?**
- **Do I actually have to kill them *via* the testicular assault or is it enough to just hit them once with it?** I've so far only been hitting them once with it. Is that not enough?
- **Does it have to be on a male character?** Saints Row 2 allowed you to get nutshots on women, but the testicular assault wasn't in that game, so I'm unsure if this is a requirement here.

Comment: I'm starting to worry if I, as a male, should continue to hang out with you... O.o

Comment: @RavenDreamer Technically you haven't hung out with her yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I did a bunch of testing on this tonight. This is what I have found:

- **The nutshot and the testicle assault do *not* have to be done on the same enemy**. The achievement simply pops after you have done each activity the first time. I killed a gang member via testicular assault without doing a nutshot on him and acquired the achievement.
- **You need to actually *kill the enemy via testicular assault* in order to get the achievement**. You'll know when you have done this because you'll see a popup for Respect with the name *Testicular Manslaughter*. Hitting an enemy twice with a testicular assault will get this done.
- **It *does* have to be done on a male character**. I tried doing testicular assaults on female gang members, and while I was able to kill them and they did the animation, I did *not* get credit for a Testicular Manslaughter.

Answer (score 1):

I got this one by:

- Shooting someone in the nuts with a pistol (thereby causing them to grab their nuts)
- Hitting them with the testicular assault, which killed them

I did this on a male rival gang member, I don't know if that was important or not.

I don't know if this is the only way to unlock it, but this is how it popped for me.

Comment: I just started playing co-op with a friend, and I told him this, he did these steps and got it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall if I got it against a male or female character, but you may wanna look at the [solutions for it on True Achievements](http://www.trueachievements.com/a156961/ow-my-balls-achievement.htm). There's usually a notice if the achievement is broken.